# PCA in thousands of dimensions

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, linear-algebra, pca

I have vectors in 4096 [VLAD codes](http://www.vlfeat.org/overview/encodings.html), each one of them representing an image.

I have to run PCA on them *without reducing their dimension* on learning datasets with less than 4096 images (e.g., the [Holiday dataset](http://lear.inrialpes.fr/people/jegou/data.php) with <2k images.) to obtain the rotation matrix `A`.

In [this paper](http://search.ieice.org/bin/summary.php?id=e99-d_10_2656) (which also explains why I need to run this PCA without dimensionality reduction) they solved the problem with this approach:

> For efficient computation of A, we compute at most the first 1,024 eigenvectors by eigendecomposition of the covariance matrix, and
>   the remaining orthogonal complements up to D-dimensional are filled using Gram-Schmidt orthogonalization.

Now, how do I implement this using C++ libraries? I'm using OpenCV, but [cv::PCA](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d8d/classcv_1_1PCA.html) seems not to offer such a strategy. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Probably the "eigen" library can help here

Comment: Btw, just reading the abstract of the paper..  why you want to do this? This doesn't seem a good paper...

Comment: @Miki why do you say that?

Comment: It's not published in a top journal/conference for computer vision.. and in 2016 it messes with sift... probably using the last layer of a googlenet as descriptor will give much better results (but I didn't read the full paper... it's just an "educated guess")

Comment: @Miki we can't integrate CNN stuff with VLAD encoding and we want something extremely fast to compute and to find the most similar image in say 10k images in few milliseconds. From my knowledge, this isn't possible using CNNs (even exploiting GPUs), while a parallel solution on classic descriptors and VLAD encoding in say 128 dimensions could be. It's a little off topic, but what you think?

Comment: I was thinking of the last FC layer to replace the vlad as final image descriptor. Then you still comparare 4096 dim vectors.... but too many details missing of course... I may be wrong

Comment: @Miki I don't know nothing about CNNs, but how do you compare two of these vectors that you're talking about? With VLAD, you use euclidean distance for that.

Comment: You can use euclidean distance as well...

Comment: @Miki do you know any already-done implementation of this? I don't know much about CNNs and I don't have much time actually to learn them. Thanks for your help btw, I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Miki beside, could you please give a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971307/hessian-affine-detector-in-opencv) question?

Comment: No idea about that... However, I think something like [this](http://www.iis.sinica.edu.tw/~kevinlin311.tw/cvpr16-deepbit.pdf) could easily solve a lot of your problems... [github](https://github.com/kevinlin311tw/cvpr16-deepbit)