# Hessian-affine detector in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, surf

I've read about this detector in many papers and articles (though I don't know it in details) and I've read that it is much better than DoG in many situations.

Initially, I thought the Hessian-affine was the SURF detector, but they're not the same thing, right?

Is there any OpenCV implementation?

Comment: This is very good implementation https://github.com/perdoch/hesaff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, no implementation of this detector in OpenCV (http://code.opencv.org/issues/1628)

No, it's not the same thing.

Long story short, SURF is a "family" of detectors and descriptors, and there are plenty of of them, as you can see it in the OpenCV documentation (http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_feature2d/py_surf_intro/py_surf_intro.html).

From what I remember DoG behave the same than Hessian affine detector usually **for natural images**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks for your answer. I know the workflow of SIFT (I don't have the math skill to understand the details) and SURF too, I heavily used them in my project. Digging a little bit a found out that the Hessian-Affine version of SIFT is called ASIFT (please correct me if I'm wrong) but it's not implemented in OpenCV. I found some OpenCV-based implementation though, like [this one](http://www.mattsheckells.com/opencv-asift-c-implementation/), but this OpenCV version is outdated. I'll try to make an updated version of it.

Comment: DoG does not behave the same as HesAff - because it lacks affine adaptation procedure. For images from very different viewpoints the difference is huge